# Codeigniter login single page

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, authentication

I have CI scripts that currently every user has their own subdomain with own mysql database.

Now I would like to have a single login page that will check the database against login details and connect to that specific database that user should run.

All CI scripts are the same but the database data is different.

I am thinking of creating a new database table where I will link which user is in which database.

Anybody have an idea of how to create this?

Comment: you can create one table for each user.

Comment: Could you explain little more

Comment: can you provide some example

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a database with one table, let's call it databasetable and fill it with the credentials of the user/db data. Then, just pick the correct details in your db_connection.php - page:

```
<?php
session_start();

$connectlogin = new mysqli ("HOST","USER_FOR_CREDENTIAL_DB","PASS_FOR_CREDENTIAL_DB","DB_CREDENTIAL_DB") or die ("nope");
if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['username']; //or whatever you POST from your login
}
else 
{
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
}


$sqla = "SELECT user_db, user_db_pass, user_db_user, user_name FROM databasetable WHERE user_name LIKE '$username'";
if ($result = $connectlogin -> query($sqla)) {


    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $user_db = $row['user_db'];
        $user_db_pass = $row['user_db_pass'];
        $user_db_user = $row['user_db_user'];
    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->free();
}
$connectlogin ->close();


$sql = new mysqli ("HOST",$user_db_user, $user_db_pass,$user_db);




$sql -> set_charset ( 'utf8' );
if ($sql->connect_errno)
    {echo "NOPE 2nd";}
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;

?>
```

For security reasons, all the credentials should be encrypted. And not be stored in the database without encryption. You need to specify encryption.